# Menu dropdown not working on successive clicks

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
function toggleMenu() {
    var mwidget = jQuery("#login_menu").menu("widget");
    var visible = mwidget.is(":visible");
    alert(visible);

    mwidget.position({
        my:'top',
        at:'bottom',
        of:$(".action")
    });

    $( "#login_menu" ).menu("refresh");
    $('#login_menu').menu().toggle();

    var visible = mwidget.is(":visible");
    alert(visible);

    return false;
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#login_menu").menu().hide();

    jQuery(".action").mousedown(function() {
        toggleMenu();
    });
});
```

I'm trying to show `menu()` from jQueryUI. The problem that comes is as follows.

Structure: as seen in the code above, I have attached a dropdown menu to the element `.action` and the menu itself is named `#login_menu`.

Desired behaviour: when I click (`mousedown` event) on button `.action` the menu should appear and then on next click the menu should disappear.

Problem: When I click 1st and 2nd time it works. But the third time the menu does not show up any more. Can anyone tell me why this is?

Comment: Probably you just want to show() or hide() your menu in toggle function. Or instead try to only this: $('#login_menu').toggle(); http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 2):

Your problem probably is `var mwidget = jQuery("#login_menu").menu("widget")`: Each time a user clicks the action link, it initializes the menu several times.

Assuming your HTML looks like this:

```
<a href="#" class="action">Action button</a>

<ul id="login-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Settings</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Along with this CSS (it is way better to do it that way rather than using hide() after pageload):

```
​#login-menu {
    display: none;
    width: 200px
}​​​​​​​
```

This code would make it work the way you want it to be. Notice that I swapped mousedown() with jQuery's click(), and "return false" with jQuery's preventDefault(). I also set the menu's position using chainable object methods instead of accessing it through a variable like you did it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#login-menu")
        .menu()
        .menu("option", "position", { 
            my:'right top',
            at:'right' });

    $(".action").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#login-menu')
            .menu("refresh") 
            .toggle();
    });

});​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
function toggleMenu()
{
    var mwidget = jQuery("#login_menu").menu("widget");

    var visible = mwidget.is(":visible");
    alert(visible);

    $('#login_menu').menu().toggle();

    var visible = mwidget.is(":visible");
    alert(visible);

    return false;
};

function posnMenu()
{
var mwidget = jQuery("#login_menu").menu("widget");

    alert("positioning the menu");

    mwidget.position({
        my:'top',
        at:'bottom',
        of:jQuery(".action")
    });

return false;
};

jQuery("#login_menu").menu().hide();

posnMenu();

jQuery(".action").mousedown(function () {
    toggleMenu();
});
```

});

just found the solution...this code works...Maybe someone can still point out why the earlier one does not work...but this time the only difference is that I am positioning it only once. So repositioning it before every toggle leads to problems...mentioned above...is this normal ?